# Specify a Default Offset for Python List

Tags: python, list, offset

Is there a way in python that you can specify a default offset for list?
Like:

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.offset = 2
```

So that whenever use index for access/modify, the index will be added by the offset first:

```py
a[0] == 2
a[4] == 6
```

Comment: you mean `a[n]` should return `a[n] + offset`? There's no built-in way , but you can create custom function or class to get this behaviour

Comment: @Anonymous, sorry for not being clear, I mean ```a[n]``` will give ```a[n + offset]```

Comment: I'm curious: why would you need this?

Comment: @AKX, I was just solving the leetcode problem [Edit Distance](https://leetcode.com/problems/edit-distance/), and I found that when I am dealing with the dynamic programming, sometimes the indices of ```dp``` list and indices of the strings are not aligned because the index of the base case is -1, so I have to either apply an offset on index of the string or index of the ```dp``` list, which is a little error-prone if doing manually.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a value for the base case that's not a valid indexer, such as  `None`?

Comment: @AKX, yeah that's an viable way in 1 dimension but I am not sure how to apply this in 2d. But I just found I can create a list with an extra space at the end so I can use ```dp[-1]``` assuming -1 index exist while actually it's just referring to the ```dp[n - 1]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in way to achieve this. However you can create your custom class by extending [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) to get this behaviour. When you do `my_list[n]`, internally [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) function is triggered. You can override this function to return the value by adding `offset` to the index.

Similarly, list contains other [*magic functions*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) which you can override to further modify the behaviour of your custom class. For example, [`__setitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) is triggered when you assign any value to list, [`__delitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) is trigger while deleting the item.

Here's a sample code to create `OffsetList` class which takes additional argument as `offset` while creating the `list`, and performs index based operations on *`index`+`offset`* value.

```
class OffsetList(list):
    def __init__(self, offset, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OffsetList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.offset = offset

    def _get_offset_index(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            key = slice(
              None if key.start is None else key.start + self.offset,
              None if key.stop is None else key.stop + self.offset,
              key.step
            )
        elif isinstance(key, int):
            key += self.offset
        return key

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        key = self._get_offset_index(key)
        return super(OffsetList, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        key = self._get_offset_index(key)
        return super(OffsetList, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        key = self._get_offset_index(key)
        return super(OffsetList, self).__delitem__(key)
```

Sample Run:

```
# With offset as `0`, behaves as normal list
>>> offset_list = OffsetList(0, [10,20,30,40,50,60])
>>> offset_list[0]
10

# With offset as `1`, returns index+1
>>> offset_list = OffsetList(1, [10,20,30,40,50,60])
>>> offset_list[0]
20

# With offset as `2`, returns index+2
>>> offset_list = OffsetList(2, [10,20,30,40,50,60])
>>> offset_list[0]
30

# Slicing support, with `start` as start+offset and `end` as end+offset
>>> offset_list[1:]
[40, 50, 60]

# Assigning new value, based on index+offset
>>> offset_list[0] = 123
>>> offset_list
[10, 20, 123, 40, 50, 60]

# Deleting value based on index+offset
>>> del offset_list[0]
>>> offset_list
[10, 20, 40, 50, 60]
```

Similarly you can modify the behaviour of other magic functions like [`__len__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__), [`__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), etc as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in Python -- or in any other language that I know of.  Your suggested syntax is reasonable, assuming that you could get the feature approved.  However, it has several drawbacks.

Until and unless this feature became common usage, you would confuse anyone trying to read such code.  Zero-based and one-based indexing are the "rule"; arbitrary indexing is a violation of long-learned assumptions.

You would seriously crimp Python's right-end indexing: the semantics aren't clear.  If someone writes `a[-1]` to access the last element, should they get that element (this is a language-defined idiom), the original `a[1]` element (per your definition), a "reflective" `a[-3]`, or `index out of bounds` trying to move two elements to the right?

---

Note that Python *does* give you the capability to define your own functionality:

**class**

Any time you don't like the given data types, you get to make your own.  You're not allowed to alter the built-in types, but you can do what you like by inheriting from `list` and writing your own `get` and other methods.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just reading data from the list, you could probably work with a subscript copy of the original:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
a = a[2:]

a[0] == 2 # True
a[4] == 6 # True
```

Keep in mind that this makes a copy of the list using the same variable name so you are losing the original content (indexes 0 and 1).  You could keep it in a separate variable if you do need it though:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
a0,a = a,a[2:]

a[0] == 2 # True
a[4] == 6 # True

a0[0] == 0 # True
a0[4] == 4 # True
```

If you really need a view on the original array with read and write capabilities, then I would suggest using a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = a[2:].view()

b[0] == 2  # True
b[4] == 4  # True

b[1] = 99
print(a)   # [ 0  1  2 99  4  5  6]
a[3] == 99 # True
```

If you want to implement something similar to numpy yourself, you could create a class that represents a "view" on a list with an internal slice property (start, stop, step):

```
class ListView:

    def __init__(self,aList,start=None,stop=None,step=1):
        self.data   = aList
        self.slice  = slice(start,stop,step)
        
    @property
    def indices(self): return range(len(self.data))[self.slice]

    def offset(self,index=None):
        if not isinstance(index,slice): return self.indices[index]
        first = self.indices[index][0]  
        last  = self.indices[index][-1] 
        step  = (index.step or 1)*(self.slice.step or 1)
        return slice(first,last+1-2*(step<0),step)         
        
    def __len__(self): return len(self.indices)

    def __getitem__(self,index): return self.data[self.offset(index)]

    def __repr__(self): return self[:].__repr__()

    def __iter__(self): return self[:].__iter__()

    def __setitem__(self,index,value): self.data[self.offset(index)] = value

    def __delitem__(self,index): del self.data[self.offset(index)]
```

usage:

```
a = list(range(1,21))

v = ListView(a,3,-2,2)

len(v)  # 8

print(a) 
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

print(v) 
# [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

v[2] += 80

print(a)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 88, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

v.slice = slice(-4,None,-3)
print(v)
# [17, 14, 11, 88, 5, 2]
```